# Can I start my project under MIT, GPLv3 or Apache 2.0 with these components?

Tags: mit, gpl-3, apache-2.0

I'm newbie in web-development. I want create a project for demo my work skills: GitHub repository with source codes and working application on some hosting service. My project is a single page application - catalog of big cities: MongoDB (from cloud service Atlas)  + Django (back-end) + React for (front-end). So licenses: SSPA for MongoDB, Django (own license) and MIT for React.

I don't know which type of license I should choose for my project and which licenses is compatibile with components licenses list. Can I start my project under MIT, GPLv3 or Apache 2.0 with these components?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check the licenses of the pieces you want to use, and see if they are compatible with the license you want to select. E.g. the FSF has a [page](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html) discussing compatibility of licences with GPL, the Open Source Initiative also has a [page](https://opensource.org/licenses) detailing licenses. David A. Wheeler wrote an [essay](https://dwheeler.com/essays/floss-license-slide.html) on the matter.

Whatever you end up doing, do heed David's admonition, ["Make Your Open Source Software GPL-Compatible. Or Else."](https://dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html) You should make sure the pieces you'll use are under GPL-compatible licenses too (even if their licenses allow your specific use), for much the same reasons.